# What was the monster's motivation in "Await Further Instructions"?

Tags: plot-explanation, await-further-instructions

In the recent horror film [*Await Further Instructions* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4971408/), a family is trapped in their house by a mysterious barrier, which is later to be revealed to be part of some kind of strange monster which is made up of thousands of black wire/tentacle like things coming out of the TV sets.

The monster causes the father to torture his family and eventually they all die except for an unborn baby, which the monster causes to be born by disintegrating the body of the dead pregnant sister. At the very end the baby is alive and the TV set shows a message to the baby - "Hello Ruby" - after which, the camera shows the exterior of the house and we see the whole neighborhood is also covered in the black mass of tentacles and I assume we are meant to understand the similar stories have played out in the other homes.

So what was all this meant to accomplish? What exactly was the black tentacle monster, why did it want the family to die and the baby to be born?

Answer (score 5):

This movie has an obvious explanation: The TVs are controlling us. In the movie, they all were so scared that they did mostly whatever the TV said. Think about reality- we say what we hear on TV, we do what we see on TV, and believe what we hear on TV. In the end, Ruby was lured to the TV and would be controlled by the TV her entire life. This shows how advertising on TV is targeting children as young as possible to control them early in life to sell things to them.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw that movie as well and was wondering about the same thing.
One possible explanation could be that this parasite monster wants to do experiments on the humans social functions, and when that is done it wants to kill them but also save some new born children just to be able to raise them in its own way and create a world with a totaly new civilazation wich is free from the problems that occur today.

As you can see there are a lot of crazy drama and rudeness among those characters right from the start in the movie, you could tell early that something isn't as it should be in that family, probably like many other families in the world.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was fairly obvious considering the tentacles looked so much like coaxial cables. Not just televisions, but all signals that carry information such as Twitter, all of the news networks, social media, everything we consume will consume us, if we let it.

*How close did we come to war through Trumps twitter account? How much propaganda did the nazis use to terrorize and kill innocent Jews?*

**Do no let yourself be led by without questioning the reason why**. That is the message I saw in this movie.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange! Your answer seems helpful and would benefit from either a reliable source or better explanation in expanding on your metaphor. :)